# Odoo check t-raw="0"

Tags: odoo, qweb

I have a template like this:

```
<template id="id1">
 <h1>Title</h1>
 <t t-raw="0"/>
</template>
```

And it is called like below:

```
<t t-call="id1">
 <div>Hello<div>
</t>
```

Or like this:

```
<t t-call="id1"/>
```

The problem is that for the second type, there's [] in the HTML. Is there a way to check if "0" has any content?

Edit: I've tried

```
<t t-if="0" t-raw="0"/>
```

And it doesn't work.

Comment: Have you tried `<t t-if="o">`

Comment: And I think your santax is wrong

Comment: please refer to https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/reference/qweb.html

Comment: Because you need to call your object as `<t t-foreach="docs" t-as="o">` then you can check if your field has any content `<t t-if="o.o">`

Comment: @KHELILIHamza It is a "0". I need to get the full content from template call.

Comment: @PravithaV The documentation doesn't have anything about checking the content within 0 magic variable.

Comment: @user3295878 did you check the "calling sub-templates" section?.

Comment: @PravithaV Yes. I got this method from there. Just need to check if there's anything within the "0" variable.

Answer (score 5):

if you have written  in your template than whenever any template calls  your template then body of the calling template is available as the raw value in variable '0'

for example 
your template

```
 <template id="id1">
     <h1>Title</h1>
     <t t-raw="0"/>
     <h2> content after calling template</h2>
 </template>
```

if you call like this

```
    <t t-call="id1">
     <div>Hello<div>
    </t>
```

then output will be like this

```
<h1>Title</h1>
 <div>Hello<div>
<h2> content after calling template</h2>
```

and if you call like this

```
     <t t-call="id1"/>
     <div>Hello<div>
```

then output will be like this

```
 <h1>Title</h1>
 <h2> content after calling template</h2>
 <div>Hello<div>
```

I hope this is helpful to understand the concept

Comment: Where can I read more about the concept <t t-out="0"/>?

Comment: @headkit here https://www.odoo.com/documentation/17.0/developer/reference/frontend/qweb.html#calling-sub-templates